# JQuery .not(next) - is it possible?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Example HTML:

```
<div class=blah>
    <div class=moreCats></div>
</div>
<div class=subCats>.......</div>

<div class=blah>
    <div class=moreCats></div>
</div>
<div class=subCats>.......</div>

<div class=blah>
    <div class=moreCats></div>
</div>
<div class=subCats>.......</div>
```

Using `slideToggle`, if I click the first div `moreCats` I want next subCats to `slideDown`, which it does. At the same time I want to `slideUp` any other open `subCats`, but, NOT the one I'm toggling or else it would close then reopen, which is what its doing.

Question: is this valid? If not is there something similar?

```
$('div.subCats').not($(this).next('.subCats')).slideUp();
```

Here's the full JQuery I'm trying

```
// show children cat items
$('#sideNav').on("click", ".moreCats", function() {         
    $('div.subCats').not($(this).next('.subCats')).slideUp(); // close all except next
    $(this).next('.subCats').slideToggle(); // slideToggle next     
});
```

Comment: `next` takes the **immediate** next element, and matches against the selector. Is that really what you need?

Comment: why don't you annotate with a class the one you are about to change and then apply the change to everything which doesn't have that class. maybe a bit similar to what you did but it probably reads better, if the class simbolizes a state.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can combine them by placing the slideToggle for the current target (which will return that element) inside `.not` and you want to select the parent's next as well

```
$('#sideNav').on("click", ".moreCats", function() {         
    $('div.subCats').not($(this).parent().next('.subCats').slideToggle()).slideUp(); 
    //or do $(this).closest('.blah').next('.subCats');
});
```

**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/A2DMz/)**

If you want to split them, then better cache the next instead of selecting it again.

```
 $('#sideNav').on("click", ".moreCats", function() {   
     var $target = $(this).parent().next('.subCats');      
     $('div.subCats').not($target.slideToggle()).slideUp(); 
     //or just do as below
    //$('div.subCats').not($target).slideUp(); 
    //$target.slideToggle()
});
```

Answer (score 1):

What you have is valid but it doesn't do what you expect, `.next()` selects the next immediate sibling element, you should first select the parent element:

```
$('div.subCats').not($(this.parentNode).next('.subCats')).slideUp();
```

You can also use `.index()` method:

```
$('#sideNav').on({
    click: function() {
       var $sub = $('div.subCats'), 
           i    = $('#sideNav .moreCats').index(this);

       $sub.not( $sub.eq(i).slideToggle() ).slideUp(); 
    }         
}, ".moreCats");
```

Answer (score 1):

`.moreCats` doesn't have any siblings so you can't use `.next()`.  What you really need is to get the next sibling of `this`'s parent.  So you go from `$(this)` > `.parent()` > `.next('.subCats')`

```
$('body').on("click", ".moreCats", function() {     
    console.log($(this).parent().next('.subCats'));
    $('div.subCats').not($(this).parent().next('.subCats')).slideUp(); // close all except next
    $(this).parent().next('.subCats').slideToggle(); // slideToggle next     
});
```

**See this [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/superscript18/tN99k/) for an example.**